# related keyword recommendation using solr and mongodb

Tags: apache, mongodb, solr, lucene, recommendation-engine

Im new to solr...

I have been looking into related content recommendation engine... for implementing it to my core php and mongodb website.. its music listening website.. so i have added keywords to every music like singer,music,lyrics to mongodb.

My question is related music recommendation using keywords can solr (more like this handler) recommend it?

example keywords : bobby-singer,a-r-rehaman,shreya goshal

its should look for related keywords in order like:

```
bobby-singer,a-r-rehaman,shreya goshal
bobby-singer,a-r-rehaman
bobby-singer,shreya goshal
a-r-rehaman,shreya goshal
bobby-singer
a-r-rehaman
shreya goshal
```

my keywords are already in mongodb.. im planning to work with apache solr morelikethis handler.. or please recommend me some good recommendation engine..

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to look at result clustering in Solr if you decide to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different things here.

1. First of all, you can use MLT to get Solr to bring to you related documents but...
2. I am wondering if you could also benefit from synonyms so that on certain searches you can get results that are similar which **may** satisfy the user
3. And also if you have already the list of relationships you can build a small index where you can run an OR of your query and get potential related searches or execute potential related searches and get related results

Hope this helps